# Drush sql-drop gives "No Tables" error

Tags: 7, database, drush

I use Site-Install to quickly setup a Drupal Site for Profile Installation Development, but I use phpMyAdmin to drop the database. I figured I might as well use Drush since it would properly be faster than using GUI.

However, after doing drush sql-drop, it says "No Tables to drop". I do drush status and I am connected to my database. I check phpmyadmin and tables are clearly seen. What's the issue here?

Comment: Please check below document

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/sql/sql-drop/

Comment: I used that document, and it still doesn't help.

Comment: You provide too little information. Maybe add the output from `drush status`?  Is the Drupal tables the only tables in the database, are you using table prefixes. I assume `drush sql-drop` returns no errors? What does `drush sqlq "show tables"`return after running `drush sql-drop`? This could of course be as simple as the Drupal database user doesn't have drop table privileges and Drush has a bug in that case?